# How to use LESS in jsfiddle to get this AngularJS calendar control to work?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm trying to get this calendar control to work in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pe4sfex6/5/

My local version of this works, and I've added everything that I can, but it seems to have a problem with the less styles which in my local HTML are in a style tag, and when I try to add it into jsfiddle, it tells me to put styles in the CSS window, but they don't work there?

**Does anyone know of a workaround to get this to work in jsfiddle?**

```
<style type="text/less">
    body { font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; }
    body>span, body>h1 { float:left; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:10px; }

    span { color:#888888;
    >b { color:black; }
    }

    .vertical-centre (@height) { height:@height; line-height:@height !important; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
    .border-box { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; }

    @border-colour:#CCC;
    calendar { float:left; display:block; .border-box; background:white; width:300px; border:solid 1px @border-colour; margin-bottom:10px;
    @secondary-colour:#2875C7;
    @spacing:10px;

    @icon-width:40px;
    @header-height:40px;

    >div.header { float:left; width:100%; background:@secondary-colour; height:@header-height; color:white;
    >* { .vertical-centre(@header-height); }
    >i { float:left; width:@icon-width; font-size:1.125em; font-weight:bold; position:relative; .border-box; padding:0 @spacing; cursor:pointer; }
    >i.fa-angle-left { text-align:left; }
    >i.fa-angle-right { text-align:right; margin-left:@icon-width*-1; }
    >span { float:left; width:100%; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; .border-box; padding-left:@icon-width+@spacing; margin-left:@icon-width*-1; text-align:center; padding-right:@icon-width; color:inherit; }
    }
    >div.week { float:left; width:100%; border-top:solid 1px @border-colour;
    &:first-child { border-top:none; }
    >span.day { float:left; width:100%/7; .border-box; border-left:solid 1px @border-colour; font-size:0.75em; text-align:center; .vertical-centre(30px); background:white; cursor:pointer; color:black;
    &:first-child { border-left:none; }
    &.today { background:#E3F2FF; }
    &.different-month { color:#C0C0C0; }
    &.selected { background:@secondary-colour; color:white; }
    }
    &.names>span { color:@secondary-colour; font-weight:bold; }
    }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/

Comment: Thanks, I updated my jsfiddle with those javascript lines and it added some lines to the output so it seems to be partially executing the LESS. I had to add jquery but I see you don't have jquery as an external resource in your jsfiddle, does it have to do with that perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pe4sfex6/4/

Comment: Yes, you have to add jquery

Comment: Right, which I did, but my jquery url shows up in "External Resources" and yours does not, I thought you might have therefore added it differently and therefore your jsfiddle works but mine doesn't.

Comment: Oh we misunderstood. I've just pointed you to aaronlayton jsfiddle to help you. It seems that aaronlayton using jquery in "frameworks & extensions" option, not in external resource.

Comment: Ok, set it the same as the jsfiddle you posted and it works for that simple example of LESS but not for my more complex example with LESS. I'm working on it here if anyone is interested in trying to solve this. :-) http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pe4sfex6/5/